# prove that if $a=b$ then $a+c=b+c$ where $a,b,c\in \mathbb R$

Tags: field-theory, relations, real-numbers, equivalence-relations, axioms

I was trying to prove if $l=m$ and $m=n$ then $l=n$ but when doing this I had to add $-m$ to both sides of both equations.i think it is not appropriate to proceed without proving "if $a=b$ then $a+c=b+c$". can anyone help? I tried many ways but every time I failed.

note: in this context when prooving $a=b \implies a+c=b+c$ one can not use 
$l=m$ and $m=n  \implies l=n$

Comment: You don't need to prove this. Or rather, you prove this using the definition of function, not field axiom.

Comment: yes. using the definition of relations proving $l=m$ and $m=n \implies l=n$ is possible.this means "if a=b then a+b=b+c"?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_of_indiscernibles

Comment: In which context do you want to prove $l = m$ and $m = n$ implies $l=n$? Usually, mathematical theories already come equipped with "equality", which would mean that what you are proving is automatically given. It depends on the particular context, though, so please include it if you want concrete help.

Comment: @Ennar I was thinking about this. $l=m$  $m=n$ implies $l=n$ for $l,m,n \in \mathbb R$. I know that this comes under common notions in Euclid's Elements. and since it is a common notion no one want to prove it.but this is the transitive property of equality. so I tried to prove it by field axioms. but then came this and it also a common notion in the book. i asked this to find out is it possible to prove this without using those common notions.

Comment: @thomson, if by "common notions" you mean undefined terms, then every theory necessarily has those, otherwise you would have circular definitions somewhere, which are considered invalid. In your case, real numbers are defined as [complete ordered field](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_number#Axiomatic_approach). Notice the part "ordered": that means that you have linear order $\leq$ defined on $\mathbb R$ and in particular notion of equality. Thus, transitivity of equality is already built in. In case you were constructing reals from rational numbers you would have something to prove.

Comment: You might be interested in [construction of the real numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Construction_of_the_real_numbers).

Answer (score 2):

Here is the thing, if you are starting from $\mathbb R$ defined by axioms of complete ordered field, or even just axioms of field, there are two [operations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_operation) that are defined on $\mathbb R$, addition and multiplication. By definition of binary operation, $+\colon \mathbb R\times\mathbb R\to \mathbb R$ is a function. It follows that for every $c\in\mathbb R$, $f_c\colon \mathbb R\to\mathbb R$, $f_c(x) = x + c$ is a function as well. Now remember that one of the defining properties of a function is the following $$a = b\implies f(a) = f(b)$$
and apply it to $f = f_c$ to get what you want. Thus, it is already encoded in the axioms just by saying that $+$ is binary operation. The same goes for multiplication.

Comment: I was thinking about this. $l=m$  $m=n$ implies $l=n$ for $l,m,n \in \mathbb R$. I know that this comes under common notions in Euclid's Elements. and since it is a common notion no one want to prove it.but this is the transitive property of equality. so I tried to prove it by field axioms. but then came this and it also a common notion in the book. i asked this to find out is it possible to prove this without using those common notions.

Comment: "Now remember that one of the defining properties of a function..."

I don't recall that as a defining property of a function.  The term 'defining property' I even find a bit strange.  Additionally, the implication you've written comes as provable without using the definition of a function all that much in a proof.

Comment: @Doug, you might want to check [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_(mathematics)#Definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_(mathematics)#Definition) then.

Comment: Thank you.  I do NOT see anything involving equality in that definition.  Without equality in the definition it appears that you do not have a defining property such that a = b implies f(a) = f(b).  Consequently, it seems logically required to provide a proof that a = b implies f(a) = f(b) for any arbitrary function f, and arbitrary members of sets 'a' and 'b'.

Answer (score 2):

Equality has the property one can replace one half of the equality with the other half in any term where the order of operations is clear.  I'll call this the replacement property of equality.

Suppose that a = b.  Then, by the replacement property of equality, specifically by replacing the 'b' with 'a', it follows that a = a.  Now 'a' was an arbitrary real number.  Thus, for any real number x,

x = x.

Since '+' is an operation, (a + c) is some real number.  By the lemma x = x, it thus follows that

(a + c) = (a + c).

Using the replacement property of equality and the hypothesis yields the result of the question.

The replacement property of equality also suffices to prove that if "l = m, and m = n, then l = n."

Answer (score 1):

There isn’t much to prove. If $a=b$, then $a+c=b+c$ by direct substitution. The converse is more interesting to prove.

That is, if $a+c=b+c$, then $a=b$.

Consider $a=a+0=a+(c+(-c))=(a+c)+(-c)=(b+c)+(-c)=b+(c+(-c))=b+0=b$. Thus $a=b$.

Answer (score 1):

So, proving the fact that $(l = m \land m = n) \implies l = n $  does not require knowing anything about $+$, it is the transitive property of equality, which is an axiom.

---

Let's prove the statement in the title anyway.

So, we have three variables, all universally qualified.

$$ (a = b) \implies (a + c = b + c) \;\forall a \forall b \forall c $$
$$ (a \ne b) \lor (a + c = b + c) \;\forall a \forall b \forall c $$

Negate the goal.

$$ (a = b) \land (a + c \ne b + c) \;\exists a \exists b \exists c \tag{NG}$$

We can add three constants to our context. Note that by doing so we are extending the theory of the real numbers to include three new constants $a, b, c$ that collectively satisfy the property we want.

$$ a = b \;\; \text{and} \;\; a+c \ne b + c\tag{101} $$

$$ a = b \tag{102} $$

The step $102 \to 103$ only requires noticing that $t \mapsto t + c$ is a function. Every function preserves equalities. A non-injective function may introduce new equalities, but no function can remove them.

$$ a + c = b + c \tag{103} $$

Pick the left expression of (101).

$$ a + c \ne b + c \tag{104} $$

(104) is the negation (103) syntactically.

$$ \bot $$